# Detecting ONLY Bar close Above Ma cross Candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I use ma crossover in trading ( ma9, ma21), I look at the condle when the crossover occur.

Then I wait for another candle that CLOSE above the high of that candle.

I want to detect ONLY the first bar that CLOSE above the candle in the crossover.

I tried different coding scripts but plot many times (not only the fisrt candle as I hope)

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

//inputs
shortlen = input.int(9, "Short MA Length", minval=1)
longlen = input.int(21, "Long MA Length", minval=1)

//Calculations
short = ta.sma(close, shortlen)
long = ta.sma(close, longlen)

//Plot
plot(long, color = #43A047, title="Long MA")

Possitive = ta.crossover  (short,long)

plotshape(Possitive, "+", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.green)

// How to identify the candle high and low when the conditions met ?

var float h = na
if Possitive
    h := high

// How to plot only on the first bar that met condition ?

// conditions
buy_signal= ta.crossover(close, h)

// plots
plotshape(buy_signal , title="Buy",text="Buy", style=shape.circle,
 color=color.rgb(67, 224, 138), size= size.tiny, location=location.belowbar)
```

Another Code

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

//inputs
shortlen = input.int(9, "Short MA Length", minval=1)
longlen = input.int(21, "Long MA Length", minval=1)

//Calculations
short = ta.sma(close, shortlen)
long = ta.sma(close, longlen)

//Plot
plot(long, color = #43A047, title="Long MA")

Possitive = ta.crossover  (short,long)

plotshape(Possitive, "+", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.green)

// How to identify the candle high and low when the conditions met ?

var float h = na
if Possitive
    h := high

// How to plot only on the first bar that met condition ?

// conditions
buy_signal= close > h

// plots
plotshape(buy_signal , title="Buy",text="Buy", style=shape.circle,
 color=color.rgb(67, 224, 138), size= size.tiny, location=location.belowbar)
```

I tried using Var but I was not capable to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right using a `var` to store the `high` price but you should also have a `bool` flag to see if you have already foudn the first candle or not.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MA Cross", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

//inputs
shortlen = input.int(9, "Short MA Length", minval=1)
longlen = input.int(21, "Long MA Length", minval=1)

//Calculations
short = ta.sma(close, shortlen)
long = ta.sma(close, longlen)

//Plot
plot(long, color = #43A047, title="Long MA")
plot(short, color = color.red, title="Short MA")

Possitive = ta.crossover  (short,long)

plotshape(Possitive, "+", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.green)

type o_cross
    bool m_is_found = false
    float m_high = na

var cross_obj = o_cross.new()

if (Possitive)
    cross_obj.m_is_found := false   // Reset the flag
    cross_obj.m_high := high    // Store the high price

buy_signal = false

if (not cross_obj.m_is_found)   // If the first bar is not found yet
    if (close > cross_obj.m_high)
        buy_signal := true
        cross_obj.m_is_found := true

// plots
plot(not cross_obj.m_is_found ? cross_obj.m_high : na, "High", color.white, 1, plot.style_circles)
plotshape(buy_signal , title="Buy",text="Buy", style=shape.circle, color=color.rgb(67, 224, 138), size= size.tiny, location=location.belowbar)
```

[image]

Comment: All you need is this [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html) and this [FAQ](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/) page.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your help I really really appreciate it.